# post commit hook fail

Tags: apache, svn, http, svn-hooks

I have Master/Slave setup using Win2k8R with SVN 1.6.9 and using TortoiseSVN 1.6.7. 
The access is through Apache and using http.
Everything works but when I commit I get the following message:
Error: post-commit hook failed (exit code 1) with output:
Error: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. 
This happen when using multiple TortoiseSVN dialog for committing the files in rapid succession. If I use one TortoiseSVN dialog and wait till the commit reply is back then I won't see the problem. In other words, committing one at the time cause no issue.
The post-commit script output is logged.

Even though I get the above error but when I check the Master and Slave repository the files have been replicated okay with no issue.

I am wondering how this issue can be solved.

Answer (score 0):

You should vote this as an issue in the [Subversion Issue Tracker](http://subversion.apache.org/issue-tracker.html).